# How can I optimize the WMS layer calls?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, leaflet, geojson, wms

I make calls to WMS layers from a remote server, these layers are large (between 150 MB and 1 Gb), the problem is when I want to display them, it takes time to recover them and display them on the map, and usually larger layers that appear faster than others.

And after every call of a WMS layer, the CPU increases to 100% which poses a problem on the server

Is there a way to optimize the response time of these layers the problem with CPU ? (On Postgresql or Javascript).

And does putting all the layers in a single directory can optimize the response time ? for example: WMS1: layers1, layers2 ... instead of WMS1: layers1, WMS2: layers2

Comment: Use WMTS, TMS, or otherwise split the images in tiles and cache those tiles.

Comment: The best way is to use WMS because this layer type contains images and also layer information in attribute format.

So there is not a way to split them. That's why I'm trying to see if there is a way to optimize it based on Javascript or for example put a cache system (Not on the browser).
There is other solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some recommendations :

- Make sure basemap and operational layers are in the same projection/coordinate system.
- Make sure large datasets are scaled to not render at all zoom levels (this is defined in the layer/WMS sld file).
- Creating tiles from WMS's.
- Make sure your client viewer is referencing the GeoWebCache tiles (url example of cached layers http://serverName.xyz.com:80/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?tiled=true).